# Defer parsing of Javascript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Ok so I know there are ton of topics about this, but I just can't wrap my head around this.

My website (bricklist.nl) is running on Laravel and seems to load content before the stylesheets, which is a bit problematic (got that feedback from users a couple of times now).

My intuition says it's because of the Javascripts in my header. GTmetrix gives me this:

456.3KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js (217.7KiB)
https://bricklist.nl/js/less.min.js (118.0KiB)
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js (87.0KiB)
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js (30.6KiB)
https://bricklist.nl/ (1.4KiB of inline JavaScript)
https://bricklist.nl/js/home.js (1.2KiB)
https://bricklist.nl/js/main.js (345B)
```

I've tried adding the 'defer' tag before each one of them, but that only screws up my layout.

Currently, this is in my head tags of the master layout:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@yield('canonical')"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
{{-- <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> --}}

<script defer src="{{ URL::asset('/js/packs/solid.min.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('css/main.less') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('css/custom.less') }}">
```

And this is in the body tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{{-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/ui-bootstrap-2.5.0.min.js') }}"></script> --}}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/less.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

I read mixed things about this topic, and I hope someone can give me suggestions about best practices for Laravel. Can anyone point me in the right direction for tackling this problem? Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a Laravel problem. Search "FOUC" for more on a fairly common issue. For example, the page spends a full second loading and executing facebook and google stuff before getting around to "resizeBricks". I didn't go through the code, but I'm assuming that's more important to the layout.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your issue with this sample. Just apply the method into your site:

Head of the page:

```html
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&amp;subset=latin-ext">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.siberfx.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</noscript>
```

End of the page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async>
/* WebFont CSS File */
var sbxSpeed_0 = document.createElement('link');
sbxSpeed_0.rel = 'stylesheet';
sbxSpeed_0.href = '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&amp;subset=latin-ext';
sbxSpeed_0.type = 'text/css';
var ParseDefer_0 = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
ParseDefer_0.parentNode.insertBefore(sbxSpeed_0, ParseDefer_0);

/* Bootstrap CSS File */
var sbxSpeed_1 = document.createElement('link');
sbxSpeed_1.rel = 'stylesheet';
sbxSpeed_1.href = '<?php echo cdn;?>css/bootstrap.min.css';
sbxSpeed_1.type = 'text/css';
var ParseDefer_1 = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
ParseDefer_1.parentNode.insertBefore(sbxSpeed_1, ParseDefer_1);
```